# TeXstudio - Jump from search line into Texteditor

Tags: texstudio

Is there a hot key to jump from a positive search result in TeXstudio from searchline to the actual result in the editor?

When I receive a review, there are a lot of colons, commas and stuff like this missing. So I'm entering the phrase, the result pops up and now I want to edit the result without changing from keyboard to mouse and back. Is there any hot key which can manage this?

If you don't know a hot key, would you think such a feature useful for your self? If so, I would at least file a feature request.

Comment: Does Focus editor (`Ctrl+Alt+Left`) work for you? As for interest for new features, you might be better off opening an issue on the project Github page (where everyone is a TXS user) and getting opinions there.

Comment: @Troy thx! Ubuntu... kills this Solution. But... reediting (I used Ctrl+1 because don't use bookmarks) the hot key in section `Optiones -> Configure TXS -> shortcuts ->  View -> Focus` helped me out =). You've saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the 'Focus editor' command built in to TXS to focus back onto the cursor in the text editor. 
By default (in Windows, TXS 2.12.8), it is binded to the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>, but you can rebind it to another key combination if it clashes with your OS-specific keyboard shortcuts, under

```
Options -> Configure TXS -> Shortcuts -> View -> Focus Editor
```

If, following that, you want to focus back into the 'Find' box, you can just use any of the 'Find'-specific shortcuts, like <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, to jump to the next found word/phrase.

Comment: is it left arrow or left click?

Comment: @naphaneal clarified.